# Iterating Pandas DF, Finding Sum After Loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the sum of the variable "candle" in the code below, but not sure how to write the code. I know someone is going to suggest using NumPy, but I don't even know where to begin with that.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    openPrice = row['open']
    closePrice = row['close']

    if closePrice - openPrice >= 0:
        candle = 0
    elif closePrice - openPrice <= 0:
        candle = 1
```

I'm looping through a dataframe that contains stock prices (open and close). I want to find the difference between the two and find the sum of the times the output is =1. Let's say the rows are: 1, 0, 0, 1. The sum should be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider following dataframe:

```
   open  close
0    20     10
1    20     30
2    20     30
3    20      5
```

---

Then you can do:

```py
df["col3"] = (df["close"] - df["open"] < 0).astype(int)
final_sum = df["col3"].sum()

print(df)
print(f"{final_sum=}")
```

This prints:

```
   open  close  col3
0    20     10     1
1    20     30     0
2    20     30     0
3    20      5     1

final_sum=2
```